# Content to variable instead of a file

Tags: vb.net

I have an application in VB.NET, what use a special API method:
[SaveAsText](http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ITableAnnotation~SaveAsText.html)

This method writes a table's content to a file.

```
Function SaveAsText( _
   ByVal FileName As System.String, _
   ByVal Separator As System.String _
) As System.Boolean
```

This works fine, but I'd like to send this method's output to some kind of "string type object" instead of a file.

The part of my code:

```
'-- myTable is a "special" object
Dim myTable As SldWorks.BomTableAnnotation = ...

...

Dim fileName As String = "C:\temptable.txt"
'--SaveAsText method writes this table's content to a file
myTable.SaveAsText(fileName, ";")
```

The output file is something like this:

```
Id;Qty;Description
1;10;Part 1
2;5;Part 2
```

That is a solution to write a file, read the content from it and delete a file, but I'd like to store this content directly into a variable or object instead of a file.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information, as well as demonstration of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I inserted a part of my code to the original post, I hope it helps little more..

Comment: As in, in the database? Or just as a temporary variable? I'd not recommend the latter, if there's gunna be large amounts of data.

Comment: My first thought was that in a temporary variable.
The table has maximum about 2.000 Rows (and 10 columns).
There is about maximum 100-200 char in each row, so the max character of the output string is about 400.000

Comment: How does `SaveAsText` work?  Are you using a `StreamWriter` to write the file?  If so, to write to a variable, you can use a `StringWriter` instead, or perhaps a `StringBuilder`

Comment: I don't know exactlyhow it works, only I know is that inputs are strings, the result is a boolean, and it creates a file.
How can I use the StringWriter/StringBuilder ?